# Can we have a tag for W3.CSS

Tags: discussion, tags

I just posted a question about w3.css (a responsive web layout from W3 consortium).

The trouble is that the commenters simply did not understand the question and I had to delete it before getting marked down (for not posting several thousand lines of w3.css code from w3 consortium).

Maybe if we had a tag for this, it would help attract the right kind of expertise and deter people who simply do not understand the question

Comment: If you need to post or refer to thousand lines of code there is something wrong with your question, not with the users that down vote that kind of useless stuff. A tag is not going to help improve question quality or change our quality criteria.

Comment: W3.css is developed by W3Schools, it has absolutely nothing to do with the World Wide Web Consortium.

Comment: W3Schools, [uh-oh](http://www.w3fools.com/).  Such a question would get DVs from both users that have no idea what the tag means *and* users that know exactly what the tag means :)

Comment: I hate both W3Schools and "people downvote me because they don't understand" rhetoric, but the core of this tag creation request seems fair. No? Not sure why it needs downvoting - w3.css seems like a legit product, and the fact that many of us don't like the source hasn't stopped us from creating tags before.

Comment: @Pekka - you're right.  Help the guy out and create the tag.  You surely ought to write the wiki as well given the W3 confuzzlement, you can no doubt do that better than me.

Comment: @rene: "*If you need to post or refer to thousand lines of code there is something wrong with your question, not with the users that down vote that kind of useless stuff.*" ... what? So we should close *every question* that's about a library with more than a thousand lines of code? Every question about Qt, Boost, etc, all ought to be downvoted and closed? w3.css seems to be the CSS equivalent of a library. I see no reason why we should be hostile to code that relies upon it.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, that is misunderstood. Without a specific question to refer to I interpreted the point of the OP as they intended to post, felt they need to or already posted thousands of lines of code, which wouldn't really help, either with or without tag. My comment was meant to indicate that maybe the question is the problem, not the (missing) tag. But I'm only speculating.

Comment: @rene: He said he was being marked down for *not* having posted it. I interpreted that to mean that comments were saying that he should have posted the CSS. Granted, posting a link to the *actual question* would have cleared all of this up...

Comment: I added a [tag:w3.css] tag to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37028726), for starters. Included the barest stub of a tag wiki entry. Edit away. Regardless of whether it addresses the concerns above, it's every bit as relevant a tag as those for other frameworks.

Comment: OK. Fact is I posted perfectly functioning valid code generated by Thymeleaf and passing HTML5 validation. Respondents told me that (1) the code did not work (which is plain wrong) and (2) that it was not valid (which is plain wrong).

Also, I have posted many questions and never had the "they don't understand me" thing happen before. 

Still, useful to learn that W3 schools have nothing to do with w3C. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say that having this tag will in any way affect the problem you cite. Especially since you neglected to post a link to the (now deleted) question.

If people were downvoting that question because it references something from W3 Schools or because it claims that W3 Schools is in any way affiliated with the actual W3C, that wouldn't change just because of a tag. If people were downvoting it because they didn't understand something about your question, attaching a tag to it wouldn't help either. It's not like that tag would suddenly give them knowledge.

The only way such a tag would have helped would be if it either:

1. Effectively warded off people who hate W3 Schools. That is, they would set that tag to their ignore list.
2. Attracted others who would have upvoted your question and argued with people in the comments.

#1 seems unlikely, and #2 causes a comment argument.

That's not to say that we shouldn't necessarily have such a tag. I'm just arguing that your reasoning doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't downvote for the w3 schools reference. I downvoted because I don't think we need a tag and OP didn't provided enough evidence that said otherwise.

Comment: @Braiam: I was referring to the question he was referencing in his post here, not his actual post here.

Comment: I was referencing the "If people are downvoting your question because" part. I'm telling you why I did downvote the post: lack of evidence to sustain the need of a new tag.

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, and by "your question", I ***meant*** the question he was referring to in his post here, not this actual Meta post.

Comment: Oh, well. Talking about ambiguities. I all the things!